# JBoss 7 management API - Delete Datasource

Tags: api, datasource, jboss7.x

I'm trying to delete programmatically a datasource that I've created in JBoss 7.

Create it was easy...

```
        ModelNode request = new ModelNode();
    request.get(ClientConstants.OP).set(ClientConstants.ADD);
    request.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).add("subsystem",
            "datasources");
    request.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).add("data-source",
        dataSourceName);

    request.get("jndi-name").set(dataSourceName);
    request.get("pool-name").set(poolName);
    request.get("use-java-context").set(Boolean.TRUE);
    request.get("connection-url").set(url);
    request.get("driver-name").set(driver-name));
    request.get("min-pool-size").set(.minPoolSize);
    request.get("max-pool-size").set(maxPoolSize);
    request.get("user-name").set(username);
    request.get("password").set("password");

    ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create(
            InetAddress.getByName(LOCALHOST), 9999);
    client.execute(new OperationBuilder(request).build());
    client.close();
```

My standalone.xml created and enabled

```
...
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.1">
  <datasources>
     <datasource jndi-name="name" pool-name="poolName" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
       <connection-url>*url*</connection-url>
       <driver>driver</driver>
       ...
      </datasource>
      <drivers>
        <driver...>
           ...
        </driver>
      </drivers>
    </datasources>
  </subsystem>
...
```

But...I can't find how to delete it programmatically. Can anybody help me?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually quite simple. You need to know the full address of the object, then simply invoke the remove operation.

```java
ModelNode request = new ModelNode();
request.get(ClientConstants.OP).set("remove");
request.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).add("subsystem",
    "datasources");
request.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).add("data-source",
    dataSourceName);

ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create(
        InetAddress.getByName(LOCALHOST), 9999);
client.execute(new OperationBuilder(request).build());
client.close();
```

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your response but it doesn't work for me :( Actually, I want update my datasource, so I delete->create->enable the datasource. Your code doesn't modify my standalone.conf and then, I can't add my modifications to the new datasource.

Comment: If you're only editing, there is probably no need to delete it first. Also it *might* need to be disabled before it's removed. I don't know off the top of my head for sure though.

Answer (score 0):

A complete API is available now to handle these kind of operations.

[Jboss Controller Operation Executer](https://github.com/techblue/jboss-controller-operation-executor)

hope this helps.